# Reading YAML in Scala without 'case class'

Tags: scala, jackson, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to read `YAML` file from `Scala` and I am able to read the file using the code given below. One of the disadvantage I see here is the necessity for me to create `case class` to have a mapping with the `YAML` file I am using. Every time I change the content of `YAML` it becomes necessary for me to change the `case class`. Is there any way in Scala to read `YAML` ***with out*** the need for me to create the `case class`. (I have also used `Python` to read `YAML` ; where we do not have the constraint of mapping a `Class` with the `YAML` structure...and would like to do similar thing in `Scala`)

**Note** : When I add a new property in `YAML` and if my `case class` do not have a matching property I get `UnrecognizedPropertyException`

```
package yamlexamples

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

object YamlTest extends App{


  case class Prop(country: String, state: List[String])

  val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())

  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  val fileStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/sample.yaml")
  val prop:Prop = mapper.readValue(fileStream, classOf[Prop])

  println(prop.country + ", " + prop.state)

}
```

`sample.yaml`(This works with code)

```
country: US
state: 
  - TX
  - VA
```

`sample.yaml` (This throws Exception)

```
country: US
state: 
  - TX
  - VA
continent: North America
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the Yaml file and load it as a collections object instead of case case. But this comes at the cost of losing typesafety in your code. The Below code uses the `load` function supported by `Yaml`. Note that the `load` has [overloaded methods](http://javadox.com/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) to read from a inputstream/reader as well..

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val yaml = new Yaml()
val data = yaml.load(
      """
        |country: US
        |state:
        |  - TX
        |  - VA
        |continent: North America
      """.stripMargin).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]].asScala
```

Now data is a scala mutable collection instead of a case class

```
data: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(country -> US, state -> [TX, VA], continent -> North America)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the YAML file using Jackson or SnakeYaml. However, Jackson does not support references/anchors, while SnakeYaml does. So, it is better to parse the YAML file using SnakeYaml & access data elements with Jackson library

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, FileReader}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{JsonNode, ObjectMapper}
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml 

// Parsing the YAML file with SnakeYAML - since Jackson Parser does not support Anchors and references
val ios = new FileInputStream(new File(yamlFilePath))
val yaml = new Yaml()
val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModules(DefaultScalaModule)
val yamlObj = yaml.loadAs(ios, classOf[Any])
    
// Converting the YAML to Jackson YAML - since it has more flexibility
val jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(yamlObj) // Formats YAML to a pretty printed JSON string - easy to read
val jsonObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString)
```

Finally, you get the JsonNode object, which enables us to convert to other datatypes.